# Prevent include PHP file from outside directory

Tags: php, html

I have one PHP Application in which my main directory is

> Application

which contains one important file called

> important.php

I want allow use important.php inside Application directory. I want prevent usage of it outside Application directory. How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: consider putting the contents of `improtant.php` in side a **php class**.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886724/prevent-access-to-files-outside-a-certain-directory-in-php) that explains it, but essentially what you need to do is use the `open_basedir` configuration parameter:

```
$basedir = "/path";
$realdir = realpath($basedir.$filename); //$filename is the parameter we checking

if (substr($realdir,0,strlen($basedir)) !== $basedir) {
  header ("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"); 
  exit; 
}
```